# How to crop an Avatar Image at it's center with ImageMagick

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, avatar

I'm trying to crop an Avatar at it's center. I've resized the image upon upload with the CarrierWave gem. The problem I have is that the avatar is then placed in a Circle and it's not centered and doesn't fill.

```
  # encoding: utf-8

  class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
    include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
     storage :file
   # storage :fog

   # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
   # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
   def store_dir
    "images"
   end

   # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file     uploaded:
   # def default_url
   #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
   #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" +  [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
   #
   #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
   # end

   # Process files as they are uploaded:
     process :scale => [400, 300]
   #
     def scale(width, height)
   #   # do something
     end

    # Create different versions of your uploaded files:

    version :profile_pic do
     process :resize_to_fit => [300, 300]
    end

    version :comment do
      process :resize_to_fit => [80, 80]
    end

   version :logged_in do
     process :resize_to_fit => [40, 40]
   end

    version :backer_avatar_page_view do
      process :resize_to_fit => [80, 80]
    end

    version  :avatar_page_view do 
      process :resize_to_fit => [300, 300]
    end

    version :page_profile_pic do
      process :resize_to_fit => [350, 350]
    end

     version :comment_post_avatar do
       process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
     end

     version :dropdown do
       process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
     end

     version :backer_avatar do
       process :resize_to_fit => [60, 60]
      end

      end
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Will you please show your code for this "then placed in a Circle and it's not centered and doesn't fill."

Comment: I figured out what I needed the images to do was :resize_to_fill instead of :resize_to_fit ... :resize_to_fill tells the image to create a version that fills all the specified dimensions where :resize_to_fit says I just want you to fit inside these dimensions.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it resolved. You could post that as answer and accept it and it might be helpful to other people who find this question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer